# Django: How to render non-Boolean database rows as checkboxes?

Tags: django, django-forms

My model:

```
class LineItems(models.Model):
    descr = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

My form:

```
class LineItemsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = LineItems
        fields = ['descr', 'cost']
```

Can someone please tell me either 1) how to render all of the product rows as checkboxes or 2) the proper way to do this if I'm coming at it incorrectly?

Comment: then why did you define the fields as DecimalField and CharField()

Comment: I'm not sure how else to define them in a database driven application. I want a database table that contains product descriptions and product costs. 

I want the user to see the description and the cost and have a checkbox to check if they want to buy it.

How else can I accomplish that? I'm (obviously) new to Django, so if I'm coming at this completely wrong, please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I was looking for. In my form:

```
LINEITEM_CHOICES = [[x.id, x.descr] for x in LineItems.objects.all()]

class LineItemsForm(forms.Form):
    food = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=LINEITEM_CHOICES,
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), required=False)
```

In my view:

```
{% for radio in lineItems.food %}
    <div class="food_radios">
    {{ radio }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

My code is based off of [this post.](http://devdens.blogspot.com/2014/04/django-multiple-choice-field-and-how-to.html)

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, then you should design your model this way:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    cost = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    # 'cost' should be a CharField because you would want to save currency name also e.g. €
```

users dont need a checkbox to buy it, I think, more appropriate way would be just an html button called "put into cart", where users can put items into cart .. and then in cart page, you give users the chance to delete the selected items again. now you think further about next steps..

Answer (score 0):

in the model form you can specify in the meta class

```
class Meta:
    widgets = {
        'descr': CheckboxInput()
    }
```

something like that anyway.
CheckboxInput is in django.forms.widgets I believe